# Wordpress Advanced Custom Field Plugin + Twig template

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, twig, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a real estate website with the template [Realia](http://themeforest.net/item/realia-responsive-real-estate-wordpress-theme/). This theme is based on Twig files and here's my problem. I have a front end submission where we can add a custom post ( a property ). I want to add a custom field to this form. The code which get and display the field is made and work because it is in a php file ;

```
<?php acf_form_head(); ?>

<?php acf_form( array(
    'field_groups' => array(1943),
    'form'  => false,
) ); ?>
```

But now I want to save the data of my field and the button "Add my property" is in a Twig file..

Here's the button code

```
      <div class="form-actions">
            {% set value = wp.__('Save', 'aviators') %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ value }}">
        </div>
    {% endif %} 

</form>
```

According to this [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/) , the acf code is `acf_form_head()` but I dunno how to put it in my code. I try `{{ acf_form_head() }}`, `{{ wp.acf_form_head() }}` and some other sentence but nothing works... I tried to to find the "save" function which is on [this php file](http://pastebin.com/76NCH3xv) but I don't know to edit it..

Please, could someone help me ?

Thank in advance

Jennifer O.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know wp-realia theme.

`{{  }}`

These tags are used for outputting some thing to browser or calling methods.
add **wp.** before calling any function **wp.** means that this functions is user defined or core function. if you call function without **wp.** prefix it means you are calling twig template function.

`{%  %}`

These tag are used for calling core twig functions eg `{% if my_var %}`.

For your scenario you want to call acf_form_head() function in header to print css/js and necessary files in the header so you can make a block in the realia/templates/helpers/header.twig file in head tag eg:

`{% block header_block %}{% endblock %}`

then in your custom twig template file reference that block and put your content in it:

```
{# we tell our custom template to extends from layout.twig #} 
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}

{# Add acf_form_head() function in our header block #} 
{% block header_block %}
    {{ wp.acf_form_head() }}
{% endblock %}

{# add this content to our content block which is define in layout.twig file #} 
{% block content %}
    {% if wp.have_posts() %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            {{ wp_query.the_post() }}
            My custom field: {{ wp.the_field('my_custom_field') }}
            {{ wp.acf_form() }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I tried `{% wp.acf_form_head() %}` but it doesn't work too...

But I have a question, `acf_form_head()` is just a fonction that I have to put in the head, so in twig it is `{{ }}` or `{%  %}` ? 

According to the [ACF documentation,](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/) it does nothing 

Do you have an idea ?