# access variables so I can display them in a twig file

Tags: php, twig, advanced-custom-fields

I am totally new to twig. So far it looks really great and I really want to learn it better. I understand the syntax so far but I don't understand where to declare variables or global variables so I can use them in my twig file. I downloaded a wordpress template that contains some twig files and I am trying to edit a single.twig file but I would like to get access to the values from my advanced custom field group specifically. I don't have symfony or timber yet. I'm also confused where the controller or environment loader is located . Can someone help me or link me to a free basic tutorial how to get variables into this twig file so I can at least display them? I hope this question is not too vague. Thank you for any help at all.

Comment: start here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300336/wordpress-advanced-custom-field-plugin-twig-template

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help without real code example, but look at twig documentation. Somewhere in code it has to call render() function, where you can pass variables

```
$twig->render('index.html', array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));
```

Comment: It could also call `$twig->display()` depending on the implementation.

Comment: yes okay. would this code be in a php file somewhere. Im not sure where to look, sorry

Comment: yes, display() function also could be, it is shortcut.